# How to get the document ID after replicating database

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am currently making a database program using couchbase on android. After I replicating the data, how can I get the document ID so I can list down all the things in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of [Queries](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html)!

If you would like to retrieve all the documents (or their IDs), you could use [All-documents query](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html#all-docs).

```
Query query = database.createAllDocumentsQuery();

QueryEnumerator result = query.run();
for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {
    QueryRow row = it.next();
    Log.w("MYAPP", "document ID: %s", row.getDocumentId()); // or QueryRow also has a way to get its source document.
}
```

You could write your own Views as per your need and later query them for results.

Also look at how to deal with document(s) in a database over [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html). In fact, I recommend going through entire guide.